# White color in TextField form in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using material ui with react. Im a beginner. Two questions:

1. How do I set the TextFields (the TextFields in the form) color to be white. The placeholder is currently black, so it the text when i write in it. I have tried to use makeStyles and set the color to white, but cant get it to work.
2. How do I set the backgroundcolor with material ui instead of doing it directly in the css. I have tried theming but that too doesnt work. I feel like setting it using material ui will make the page more dynamic, or is that just not the way of doing it?

I have struggeled with this for days, and im probably doing something wrong. So, I need help.

[A link to how the site looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZY7X.png)

Here is the code. Its not much:

App.js:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    textField: {
      width: "100%",
    },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hi");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={6}></Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
          <Typography variant="h2" color="primary">
            Some information about you
          </Typography>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              label="Name"
              variant="filled"
              className={classes.textField}
            ></TextField>
            <TextField
              label="Phone Number"
              variant="filled"
              className={classes.textField}
            ></TextField>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #39445a;
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a sandbox and share the link?

Comment: Use `inputProps` to set the `input` element properties. More here https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api

Comment: Here is the link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-material-ui-with-react-dcnsj?file=/public/index.html

Comment: @SelvaS so i could to it like this: const inputProps = {
  color: "white",
}; ?

Comment: Do you want to color the label in white or the textbox text in white?

Comment: Want to color the text and the placeholder text in the TextField wich is an input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CSSBaseLine](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/) if you want to use your own background rather than the theme provided by the browser. Also if you want to customize your own theme you should use [createMuiTheme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) Also I've tried to improve your code structure by creating a separate theme and APPForm file and a separate APP.js file. It helps code readability.

```
//Theme.js
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const arcBlue = "#0B72B9";
const arcOrange = "#FFBA60";

export default createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    common: {
      arcBlue: `${arcBlue}`,
      arcOrange: `${arcOrange}`
    },
    primary: {
      main: `${arcBlue}`
    },
    secondary: {
      main: `${arcOrange}`
    }
  },
  typography: {
    h3: {
      fontWeight: 200,
      fontSize: "2rem"
    },
    TextField: {
      fontFamily: "Raleway",
      fontWeight: "700",
      textTransform: "none",
      fontSize: "1rem"
    }
  }
});
```

```
//APPForm.js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

function Form() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    textField: {
      ...theme.typography.TextField,
      width: "100%"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hi");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={6}></Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
          <Typography variant="h2" color="primary">
            Some information about you
          </Typography>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              label="Name"
              variant="filled"
              className={classes.textField}
            ></TextField>
            <TextField
              label="Phone Number"
              variant="filled"
              className={classes.textField}
            ></TextField>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

```
//APP.js

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

import Form from "./Form.js";
import theme from "./Theme";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline /> // using cssBaseLine
        <Form />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

There are a lot of property you can use. Follow the official doc of material UI. Here you can customize your [theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) property.

Comment: Not sure if i understood that. Can I do it somthing like this?: """overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            backgroundColor: "#0B72B9"
        }
    }""" This wont work, but is this how I set the background color of the entire page?

Comment: Only had to write palette: {
    type: "dark", } and add add cssBaseline as you did. Problem solved